# Inertia handle null in share middleware

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

```
    public function share(Request $request)

    {

        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [

            'darkMode' => !!$request->user()->dark_mode,

        ]);

    }
```

So the code above is saying "use darkMode" once a user is logged in. The issue is, if a user is NOT logged in it comes back as NULL. How do I set a default value if it comes back as null (the default would be "false")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```php
public function share(Request $request)
{
   return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
      'darkMode' => Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->dark_mode : false,
   ]);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - I figured it out the next day but forgot to come back and mark it as correct - you got it!